# Overlay a video and an image over a background video and shift that background video's position to the right

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, overlay

I'm currently working on a way to improve my production process for the videos that I'm making. I usually edit videos using two folders full of clips. Being able to automate putting these together in Premiere would save me a lot of time.

I'm using the FFMpegCORE C# library, as well as Xabe.FFMpeg to achieve what I'm trying to do, and I've currently reached the point of creating two separate videos using the clips I mentioned earlier.

The final step that I need to solve is to overlay the overlay video (overlay.mp4) over the background video (background.mp4), add an overlay image to add a clean divider (overlay.png) between the edges of the videos, and to somehow shift the position of the background video 33% to the right (background.mp4).

This is the script I've come up with so far:

```
ffmpeg -i overlay.mp4 -i background.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex \ 
"[1:v]scale=608:1080[a]; [0:v]pad=1920:1080[b]; [b][a]overlay[out]; \
[out][2:v]overlay[out]; [0][1]amix[a];" \
-map [out] -map [a] -c:v libx264 -crf 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4
```

Is there a way to shift the background video to the right? Or should I manually edit the video files?

Would love some help here, also eager to learn more about FFmpeg, so some explanation would be highly appreciated!

Edit:

Just found the solution, padding the background video for 33% and then cropping the final out back to 1920x1080 seemed to do the trick!

```
ffmpeg -i overlay.mp4 -i background.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=608:1080[a]; [0:v]pad=2560:0:x=1920:y=1080[b]; [b][a]overlay[out]; [out][2:v]overlay[out]; [out]crop=1920:1080:0:0[out]; [0][1]amix[a];" -map [out] -map [a] -c:v libx264 -crf 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4
```